# Testing rows of a 2D vector with unordered map

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-map

I generate a 2D vector and want to check how often specific words appear in one row of the vector.
Here is an example of my vector:

```
Monkey Monkey Banana
Banana Monkey Monkey
Banana Banana Banana
```

I want the result:

`First row: Monkey: 2 of 3`

`Second row: Monkey: 2 of 3`

`Third row: Banana: 3 of 3`

With my code I don't know how to get the rows out of my 2D vector. I can get the columns like presented in the code.
Here is the code:

```
vector<string> read_file(string filename) {
   string classname;
   vector<string> v_classname;

   ifstream myfile(filename);
   while (myfile >> classname)
       v_classname.push_back(classname);

return v_classname;}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 

    int num;
    vector<vector<string>> class_matrix;
    vector<string> v_classes;


    cout << "Enter number vectors: " << endl;
    cin >> num;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        string name;



        cout << "Enter name of file " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> name;

        v_classes = read_file(name);
        class_matrix.push_back(v_classes);


    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {

    unordered_map<string, size_t> m;
    for (const auto& s : class_matrix[i])
        ++m[s];

    for (const auto& p: m)
        cout << i+1 << ". column: " << p.first << "\t" << p.second << " of " << v_classes.size() << endl;
}



return 0;}
```

Comment: You are using a vector above... Just use it and loop through it with a nested for-loop... there's no reasonable use case of using an unordered_map here, and also, your code doesn't even show it. If the problem is, that you read the columns, you index incorrectly. If you read whole-rows from a file, you need to have the rows as the first, the columns as the second index.

Comment: First, indent your code. Second, your program doesn't attempt to print any of "first" or "row" or "of",  doesn't compute any maximums, and only processes one row, so it isn't very clear why you expect its  output to match your desired output.

Comment: Ok, I thought I need unordered map to count the occurences of my words. How can I count the occurences in a nested for-loop if I don't know the words I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for being so late. This function can help you:

```
void CalcMostFrequentInRow( const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& input )
{
    std::vector<std::multimap<size_t, std::string, std::greater<size_t>>> VectorAllData;// Holds elements max_repetitions => key in each row. All data stored here
    for ( auto SubVector : input )
    {
        std::map<std::string, size_t> TempCounterMapByKey; // Holds key => max_repetitions
        std::multimap<size_t, std::string, std::greater<size_t>> TempKeysCounterMapByCount; // For current roe holds max_repetitions => key descending with a help of std::greater

        std::for_each(SubVector.begin(), SubVector.end(), [&TempCounterMapByKey]( const std::string& key )
                      {
                          TempCounterMapByKey[key]++; // Counter of unique key in row
                      });
        std::for_each(TempCounterMapByKey.begin(), TempCounterMapByKey.end(), [&TempKeysCounterMapByCount]( const auto pair )
                      {
                          TempKeysCounterMapByCount.insert(std::make_pair(pair.second, pair.first));
                      });

        VectorAllData.push_back(TempKeysCounterMapByCount); // Save data statistic for each row

    }

    //Trace all data
    size_t RowId = 1;
    const size_t COUNT_ROWS = VectorAllData.size();
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < COUNT_ROWS; i++ )
    {
        auto El = VectorAllData[i];
        std::cout << "Row " << RowId++ << " contains";
        const size_t COUNT_KEYS_IN_ROW = input[i].size();
        if( El.size() > 0 )
        {
            size_t MostFrequentIdCount = El.begin()->first;
            auto range = El.equal_range(MostFrequentIdCount);// Range of most frequent elements
            const size_t CountMostFrequentElements = El.count(MostFrequentIdCount);

            // Specific trace if we have several elements with max counter of most frequent keys
            if ( CountMostFrequentElements > 1 )
            {
                std::cout << " several most frequent elements(" << MostFrequentIdCount << " repetition of " << COUNT_KEYS_IN_ROW <<  ") and their value is: ";
                std::for_each(range.first, range.second, []( const auto El )
                              {
                                  std::cout << El.second << ", ";
                              });
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
            else // Specific trace if we have one element with max counter of most frequent keys
            {
                std::cout << " one most frequent element(" << MostFrequentIdCount << " repetition of " << COUNT_KEYS_IN_ROW <<  ") and its value is: ";
                std::for_each(range.first, range.second, []( const auto El )
                              {
                                  std::cout << El.second << " ";
                              });
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are comments in code everywhere, hope everything is understand. So for your program you can just call:

```
vector<vector<string>> class_matrix;
//...
//Input data
//...
CalcMostFrequentInRow(class_matrix);
```

Everything should work. For example I will show my test input data:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> InputVector {{"qwe","qwe","rty"}, {"rty","qwe","rty"}, {"asd","asd","asd"}, {"asd","qwe","rty"}};
    CalcMostFrequentInRow(InputVector);

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
Row 1 contains one most frequent element(2 repetition of 3) and its value is: qwe 
Row 2 contains one most frequent element(2 repetition of 3) and its value is: rty 
Row 3 contains one most frequent element(3 repetition of 3) and its value is: asd 
Row 4 contains several most frequent elements(1 repetition of 3) and their value is: asd, qwe, rty,
```